# set euid with posix_spawn

Tags: c, macos, unix, posix

I have the following code snippet.

```
char *const parmList[] = {"sh", "-c", "whoami", NULL};
if(geteuid() == 0) {
   seteuid(atoi(getenv("SUDO_UID")));
}
posix_spawn(&pid, "/bin/sh", NULL, NULL, parmList, environ);
```

From my understanding the default behavior of `posix_spawn` is:

> If the `POSIX_SPAWN_RESETIDS` flag is not set, the child process shall inherit the parent process' effective user ID.

However, when I run my program with `sudo`, I still get `root` as the output from `posix_spawn`. How do I have it so posix_spawn will run as the original user? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Any reason you only make the pointers to the literals `const`, but not the vaslues they point to?

Comment: @Olaf no, I'll edit that out. That didn't change the root issue tho.

Comment: Can you run `strace -f` on your command and check whether the shell is resetting the euid? Many shells, if they see that ruid != euid, will reset the euid to match.

Comment: I actually meant to make the dereferenced pointers `const`, too.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean @Olaf. `posix_spawn` takes a `char *const argv[restrict]` which I thought is what I had earlier

Comment: Ok, then your code might invoke undefined behaviour, String literals shall not be modified, which that declaration allows. Might be a irrelevant legacy, though, but you should use modifyabnle arrays for the arguments (e.g. use compound literals).

Comment: Have you checked the values returned by `getenv()` and `atoi()`?  You can get 0 back from `atoi()` rather easily, in which case, your `seteuid()` call is doing what you told it to do: setting the EUID to 0 aka `root`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up accomplishing this by creating a function that `fork`s then `exec`s

```
pid_t runCmd(char *cmd) {
    if(!cmd) return -1;

    pid_t ans = fork();
    if(ans == 0) {
        if(geteuid() == 0) {
            int uid = atoi(getenv("SUDO_UID"));
            setreuid(uid, uid);
        }
        if(verbose_flag) println("uid %d; euid %d", getuid(), geteuid());
        char *const parmList[] = {"sh", "-c", cmd, NULL};
        execv("/bin/sh", parmList);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

`whoami` now returns the original user

Comment: IMO, `posix_spawn()` is the spawn of the devil — an incredibly complex solution to a non-problem.  AFAIK, the `fork()` and `exec()` paradigm can sort out all the issues that `posix_spawn()` and its related functions can sort out, with a lot less coding.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, there's an overhead when forking a large process, as `fork` requires twice the amount of memory of the parent process. `posix_spawn` addresses this problem and you can read more about it and fork's performance issues, in detail, [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/subprocess-136439.html)